# is "mutual compatibility" tautological?

Tags: meaning

By definition, `compatibility` means

```
a state in which two things are able to exist or occur together without problems or conflict
```

Thus, are there situations where there is one-sided compatibility or are all "compatibilities" mutual, which makes the term "mutual compatibility" tautological.

Comment: "Mutual compatibility" simply emphasizes a that A is highly acceptable to B and vice versa.  Despite your rather narrow definition, "compatibility" can sometimes be uni-directional.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks. Can you exemplify your point on uni-directional compatibility ? Thanks

Comment: When a young woman, speaking of her latest amour, tells her buddy that "We're just not compatible."

Comment: To me, your example illustrates my point. She wouldn't have said "we are/are not uni-directional compatible", as in compatibility has to be mutual by definition, no?

Comment: And you miss my point:  He thinks everything is hunky-dory.

Comment: Think of blood type compatibility. Type-O-negative individuals are compatible *as donors* with all other blood types, but they aren't compatible with anyone else *as recipients*.  Type-AB-positive is the opposite: they're universal recipients (everyone is compatible with them) but can't donate to anyone but other AB+s (they aren't compatible with anyone else).

Answer (score 1):

It is true that, in most cases, the word *mutual(ly)* is redundant in the sentences like ‘A and B are mutually compatible’, as it does not add anything to ‘A and B are compatible’.

There are, however, some cases where that word is a useful tool for avoiding the risk of ambiguities. Suppose that the context involves some discussion of more than two things, say, A, B, and C. If one were to say, in such a context, ‘A and B are compatible’, this can be ambiguous between

A is compatible with B

and

A is compatible with C, and B is compatible with C.

In such a case, saying ‘A and B are mutually compatible’ makes it clear that one’s intended meaning is the former.

Comment: Yes. And contrast this with "mutually incompatible"—a perfectly acceptable phrase in which A can be applied to C, and B can be applied to C, but A and B cannot both be applied to C at the same time.